# How can I duplicate a sheet using apps script on the google sheets app when it opens the spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a custom function that duplicates a sheet in a spreadsheet and renames it. I tried using the trigger onOpen but it didn't work on the google sheets app (android). I also tried to create a web app to make it do this on the app but it doesn't work either. Here's the function:

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index.html")
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function onOpen() {

var activeSSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = activeSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet0');

sheet.copyTo(activeSSheet).setName('Sheet1').activate();
//duplicate.setName('Sheet1');
}
```

And the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
        function redirect() {
            window.open("SPREADSHEETLINK","SPREADSHEETNAME");
        google.script.run.onOpen();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="redirect()">
</body>
</html>
```

I picked up this code on the internet and I modified it. It works on PC but on my phone it doesn't work. I don't know if it has something to do with a restriction in the app it self or what. I'm kind of new to programming so I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Try using an installable onOpen trigger

Comment: I tried using an onOpen trigger. This is how it was before but it didn't work in the app, well actually I remembered that when I opened it, the sheet was duplicated but then it disapeared. So I have no clue if it's a configuration or something.

Comment: The point of using an installable trigger is that they are able to perform operations that require permission.  Simple triggers cannot.

Comment: Yeah I was checking here and I tried it as well, I did it again just to make sure. So here's what happened: I opened the SpreadSheet on my phone and for some reason it notifies me repeatedly that "All files are now available offline". I created this function and added it to my triggers, thats an installable trigger right?

Comment: Well now that I look a little closer I would suggest not using onOpen that way. It’s meant to respond to simple triggers. I think you should be using SpreadsheetApp.GetActive() or SpreadsheetApp.openById() and if you’re on a mobile you should probably be accessing via a we app.

Comment: When I access the web app link it doesn't allow me to edit, so I'm redirected to the app and still it doesn't execute when I open. :/

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `var sheet = activeSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet0');` it should be **activeSSheet** and also make sure you do have a "Sheet0" otherwise there is nothing to copy.

If that is in place, you go without having to call `onOpen()` from the client.

Like:

```js
function redirect() {
  window.open("SPREADSHEETLINK","SPREADSHEETNAME");
  // google.script.run.onOpen();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I saw it and changed it, it still won't work. :/ The problem is that it works on PC but not on mobile.

Comment: You should edit the title of your question accordingly

Comment: Yeah, I tried explaining it better in the description. Also, I ran the code without the onOpen and it just renamed the current sheet.